# Read every time BLE characteristics

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an app that comunicate from BLE device. This device have two characteristics. I want to read all value of this characteristic al long as the devices have value of that characteristic.

So I'm building a simple Activity that read the value of this sensor. But the problem are two:

1. With my code, I can read also one value at a time, I'm not able to scan all value of the Sensor BLE.
2. I'm not able to read the second characteristic. If I try to read one characteristic a time I can read its. If I try to read characteristic 1 and 2 I'm able to read only the first characteristic.

So this is my GattCallBack class:

```
private class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            Log.i("tag","onConnectionStateChange newState: " + newState);

            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
                logError("Connection Gatt failure status " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // handle anything not SUCCESS as failure
                logError("Connection not GATT sucess status " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            }

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.i("INFO","Connected to device " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                setConnected(true);
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.i("INFO","Disconnected from device");
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.i("INFO","Device service discovery unsuccessful, status " + status);
                return;
            }

            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics = BluetoothUtils.findCharacteristics(gatt);
            if (matchingCharacteristics.isEmpty()) {
                logError("Unable to find characteristics.");
                return;
            }

            Log.i("INFO","Initializing: setting write type and enabling notification");
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : matchingCharacteristics) {
                //characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
                enableCharacteristicNotification(gatt, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.i("INFO","Characteristic written successfully");
            } else {
                logError("Characteristic write unsuccessful, status: " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            Log.i("INFO","Characteristic changed, " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

        private void enableCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            boolean characteristicWriteSuccess = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            if (characteristicWriteSuccess) {
                try{
                    Log.i("INFO","Characteristic notification set successfully for " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                    //commento per il momento questa parte di codice
                    gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                if (BluetoothUtils.isEchoCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                    initializeEcho();
                }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }

            } else {
                logError("Characteristic notification set failure for " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.i("INFO","Characteristic read successfully");
                readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            } else {
                logError("Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: " + status);
                // Trying to read from the Time Characteristic? It doesnt have the property or permissions
                // set to allow this. Normally this would be an error and you would want to:
                // disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }


        private void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            byte[] messageBytes = characteristic.getValue();
            Log.i("INFO","Read: " + StringUtils.byteArrayInHexFormat(messageBytes));
            String message = StringUtils.stringFromBytes(messageBytes);
            if (message == null) {
                logError("Unable to convert bytes to string");
                return;
            }

            Log.i("INFO","Received message: " + message);
        }
    }



public class BluetoothUtils {

    // Characteristics

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public static List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> findCharacteristics(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt) {
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics = new ArrayList<>();

        List<BluetoothGattService> serviceList = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
        BluetoothGattService service = BluetoothUtils.findService(serviceList);
        if (service == null) {
            return matchingCharacteristics;
        }

        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicList = service.getCharacteristics();
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristicList) {
            if (isMatchingCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                matchingCharacteristics.add(characteristic);
            }
        }

        return matchingCharacteristics;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    @Nullable
    public static BluetoothGattCharacteristic findEchoCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt) {
        return findCharacteristic(bluetoothGatt, CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_STRING);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    @Nullable
    private static BluetoothGattCharacteristic findCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt, String uuidString) {
        List<BluetoothGattService> serviceList = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
        BluetoothGattService service = BluetoothUtils.findService(serviceList);
        if (service == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicList = service.getCharacteristics();
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristicList) {
            if (characteristicMatches(characteristic, uuidString)) {
                return characteristic;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public static boolean isEchoCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        return characteristicMatches(characteristic, CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_STRING);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private static boolean characteristicMatches(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, String uuidString) {
        if (characteristic == null) {
            return false;
        }
        UUID uuid = characteristic.getUuid();
        return uuidMatches(uuid.toString(), uuidString);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private static boolean isMatchingCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (characteristic == null) {
            return false;
        }
        UUID uuid = characteristic.getUuid();
        return matchesCharacteristicUuidString(uuid.toString());
    }

    private static boolean matchesCharacteristicUuidString(String characteristicIdString) {
        String[] stringSequence = new String[] {CHARACTERISTIC_TEMPERATURA_STRING};
        return uuidMatches(characteristicIdString, stringSequence);
    }

    // Service

    private static boolean matchesServiceUuidString(String serviceIdString) {
        return uuidMatches(serviceIdString, SERVICE_STRING);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    @Nullable
    private static BluetoothGattService findService(List<BluetoothGattService> serviceList) {
        for (BluetoothGattService service : serviceList) {
            String serviceIdString = service.getUuid()
                    .toString();
            if (matchesServiceUuidString(serviceIdString)) {
                return service;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // String matching

    // If manually filtering, substring to match:
    // 0000XXXX-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    private static boolean uuidMatches(String uuidString, String... matches) {
        for (String match : matches) {
            if (uuidString.equalsIgnoreCase(match)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this two problems ?

Comment: Reading or writing should be serialized in andorid BLE, you cant get two values at single time. You have to make sure that you dont call any other command(read,write) until you get response for previous command.

Comment: mmm, so how can I change my code to can read the two characteristics ?

Comment: You have to read one characteristic at a time, one after other, Create a queue of commands( read or write ). call a method " to request value from characteristic " from onCharacteristicWrite() refer this : https://gist.github.com/BALUSANGEM/050425bccef32784ffb32a1fcb5eedec

Comment: check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638870/how-can-read-all-characteristics-value-of-my-ble-device/48643768#48643768)